# Proving a Binomial Identity

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

**Problem $\boldsymbol{25}$ [$\boldsymbol{5}$ Points]:** Show that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}{k}\frac1{2^k}=2^n
$$
*Hint: Denote  the left hand side by $f(n)$ and prove that $f(n+1)=2f(n)$.*

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RYs1.jpg)

Can you please help me with problem 25. I need to prove that $f(n+1)=2 f(n)$, where $f(n)$ is the LHS of the expression, from there on I can do it my self. I have tried using the binominal theorem and using different summation identities but i just cant get there. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried using Pascal's Identity $$\binom{n + 1}{k} = \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k - 1}$$ for $k \geq 1$?

Comment: I would try using a combinatorial proof (i.e. Don't use their hint or induction). Hint: $2^{n}$ is the number of subsets of a set of size $n$.

Comment: i have tried using pascal identity but still no good and using a combinatorial proof would be extremely difficult because the size of the set would change(we have n+k not only n)

Comment: It might be worth noting that $\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\begin{matrix}n\\k\end{matrix}\right) = 2^n = f(n)$.

Comment: @GDumphart that is not true at all. For $n=4$ and $k=2$, $\binom{4}{2}=6$ and $\binom{6}{2} = 15$.

Comment: ^ I just found and edited my flaw. I naively thought the summands should be the same (polynomial mindset).

Comment: I think it is interesting the the sum from $k=0$ to $k=n$ is exactly $\frac12$ of the sum from $k=0$ to $k=\infty$. Is there a nice explanation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Showing the hint is just a straightforward calculation. If $f(n) = \sum \binom{n+k}{k} \frac{1}{2^k}$, then
\begin{align*}
f(n+1) &= \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+k+1}{k} \frac{1}{2^k} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \binom{n+k}{k-1} \frac{1}{2^k} + \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+k}{k} \frac{1}{2^k} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+k+1}{k} \frac{1}{2^k} + \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+k}{k} \frac{1}{2^k} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[ \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+k+1}{k} \frac{1}{2^k}  - \binom{2n+2}{n+1}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right] \\
&\quad + \left[ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n+k}{k} \frac{1}{2^k} + \binom{2n+1}{n+1} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} f(n+1) + f(n) + \frac{1}{2^{n+2}} \left[ 2\binom{2n+1}{n+1} - \binom{2n+2}{n+1} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} f(n+1) + f(n),
\end{align*}
and so $f(n+1) = 2f(n)$. Now, showing the result follows by induction.

Comment: thanks man it was very helpful indeed... this is what i actually did but just couldnt do the last couple of rows.... thanks a lot.